# How can I remove an embedded array in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, object, pull

I have a collection like:

```
{
"_id" : "oBmLTMB5Y6gWwkYML",
"mailingAddresses" : [
    {
        "addressId" : "sEK4cza8XBHBApF2P",
        "streetAddress" : "asdf",
        "streetAddress2" : "fdsa",
        "city" : "asdfasdf",
        "state" : "DC",
        "zip" : "2201512"
    },
    {
        "addressId" : "behnKE3THzcS9sH5E",
        "streetAddress" : "ffff",
        "streetAddress2" : "ddd",
        "city" : "asdfsdf",
        "state" : "CA",
        "zip" : "99995"
    }
]
}
```

How can I remove an entire address object? For example, I want to remove the address with id `sEK4cza8XBHBApF2P`. I have tried:

`db.users.update({_id: 'oBmLTMB5Y6gWwkYML'}, {$pull: {'mailingAddress': {addressId: 'sEK4cza8XBHBApF2P'}}})`

But it only returns 'nMatched: 1' and does not remove that address object.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: 
$pull can be used to remove embedded array:

```
db.users.update({_id: 'oBmLTMB5Y6gWwkYML'}, {$pull: {mailingAddresses: {addressId: "sEK4cza8XBHBApF2P" }}})
```